# How to find the submit button in a specific form in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to get jQuery object of a submit button in a specific form (there are several forms on the same page).

I managed to get the form element itself. It looks something like this:

```
var curForm = curElement.parents("form");
```

The current Element has the context HTMLInputElement. The several techniques I tried to get the according submit element of the form:

```
var curSubmit = curForm.find("input[type='submit']");
var curSubmit = $(curForm).find("input[type='submit']");    
var curSubmit = curForm.find(":submit");
var curSubmit = $(curForm).find(":submit");    
var curSubmit = $(curSubmit, "input[type='submit']");
```

the result is always the same (and very strange). The result that I get is the same element as "curElement".

So how can I get the right submit button?

Comment: That should work.  Can you show an example, perhaps on http://JSBin.com?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

The following should work:

```
var submit = curElement.closest('form').find(':submit');
```

Comment: +1 for :submit! So much easier to use those than attribute selectors.

Comment: `':submit'` some browsers also consider normal button in form as submit button & jQuery return all buttons.

Answer (score 20):

This should work:

```
var curSubmit = $("input[type=submit]",curForm);
```

**EDIT:** Note the missing `'` in the selector

Answer (score 17):

Using plain javascript (without relying on jquery):

```
var curSubmit = curForm.querySelector('button[type="submit"]');
```

Comment: What if there is an inner form with another submit button?

Answer (score 9):

This works for me:

```
var curSubmit = $("input[type=submit]",this);
```

where **this** mean current form submitted

for ex. to get the name of submitted button and all inputs submitted

```
$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = $(this).serialize(); //all input variables  
    console.log(data); //print data in console
    var submit = $("input[type=submit]",this).attr('name'); 
    alert(submit); // name of submit button
});
```

Comment: In the first example.. shouldn't it be '$(this)' instead of plain 'this'?

Comment: @Pixel1002 the $ is around this and "input[type=submit]"

Answer (score 5):

Because a HTML5 submit button may be out of form tag http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.submit.html#input.submit.attrs.form, you can use the following code to find it:

```
$(curElement.closest('form').get(0).elements).filter(':submit')
```

Comment: I don't know why you got down-voted, this is the answer I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

In case you want to find the submit button of the form after it was submitted, you may find the following useful ... I use it to disable the submit button after the form was submitted to prevent multiple clicks.

```
$("form").submit(function () {
  if ($(this).valid()) { // in case you have some validation
    $(this).find(":submit").prop('disabled', true);
    $("*").css("cursor", "wait"); // in case you want to show a waiting cursor after submit
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

BTW: Last selector looks weird. It selects each curSubmit(hm?) in every `input[type=submit]` tag. May be you mean `var curSubmit = $("input[type=submit]", curForm);`