# Grab a form's submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am attempting to grab a form's submit button in order to remove the `disabled` attribute from the submit button.

I listen for the form submission:

```
$(".some-class-on-the-form").submit(function(e) {
  ...
});
```

I can find the form just fine within the context of that listener:

`this.closest('form');`

Now I need to grab the `submit` button associated to this form.  I don't want to add an `id` or `class` to this submit button because I need it generic for a bunch of forms.

Easiest way I can think of is to search for an element with the `type="submit"`, but it keeps erroring out:

```
this.closest('form').find("input[type=submit]");
```

Returns this error in the console:

> TypeError: this.closest('form').find is not a function. (In 'this.closest('form').find("input[type=submit]")', 'this.closest('form').find' is undefined)

I have also tried this which was suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892683/how-to-find-the-submit-button-in-a-specific-form-in-jquery) but I get the same error:

```
this.closest('form').find(':submit');
```

I also did review the [jquery doc on :submit](https://api.jquery.com/submit-selector/).

**Question**: I find the form just fine.  Now: how do I find the submit button associated to the form?

Comment: what is the html for this

Comment: try $(this).closest('form')

Comment: I find the form just fine.  It is finding the submit button within the form that I am having trouble.

Comment: What is the context of `this`? What makes you think it finds the form fine? `this.closest('form').find is not a function` certainly implies that it doesn't

Comment: can you not do this.closest('form button'); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(this).closest('form').find('button[type=submit]')
```

This will do the trick.

Comment: Pure speculation, we don't even know what `this` is

Comment: @Virushabadoss your previous answer worked for me.  This one does not.

Comment: @andrew `$(this)` is the element holding the form.

Comment: well `$(this)` is not the same as `this`

Comment: Besides, if `this` is the element containing the form the above would not work, `this` would need to be an element within the form in order for it to work

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the form as a jQuery object:

```
$(this.closest('form')).find("input[type=submit]");
```